# Checking definedness of nested object's fields in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Take an object like this

```
book.chapter.paragraph.sentence.word
```

assume you want to retrieve a certain word

```
book[6][3][15][3]
```

to be certain to reference an existing word, do you really have to perform a check like this...

```
if(typeof book[6] !== "undefined" && typeof book[6][3] !== "undefined" && typeof book [6][3][15] !== "undefined" && typeof book[6][3][15][3] !== "undefined") ...
```

...or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Normally for dynamic access to nested properties you are expected to make an iterative check. However you might also use a try catch and parse the error message ugliness to access the undefined property. Such as

```js
try{
var book = {page111: {paragraph2:{sentence4:{word12:"test"}}}};
    list = ["page112","paragraph2","sentence4","word12"],
    word = book[list[0]][list[1]][list[2]][list[3]];
    console.log(word);
}catch(e){console.log(list[list.indexOf(e.message.match(/\'(.*)\'/)[1])-1], "is undefined")}
```

I have to agree that it is very ugly.

Comment: You say that an iterative check is expected: this was, in fact, my first idea. I thought it would be an atrocious solution, but if it is the norm as you imply, I would go for that. I assumed there could be a built-in function for this kind of iterative check, that I was somehow missing...